# unexpected error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int

Tags: python

My code is giving error after the second iteration, but I can't detect the problem. The return reports: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
But the two variables are INT and the code only reacts like that after the second iteration.

```
numero = int(input('Olá. Sou seu computador...\nAcabei de pensar em um número entre 1 e 
10.\nSerá se você consegue advinhar qual foi? \nQual é seu palpite? '))
import random
sorteado = random.randint(1,11)
print(sorteado)
tot=1
print(type(sorteado))
print(type(numero))
while numero != sorteado:
    if numero < sorteado:
        numero = print(int(input('Mais...tente mais uma vez!')))
        tot+=1
    elif numero > sorteado:
        numero = print(int(input('Menos...tente mais uma vez!')))
        tot+=1
print('Parabéns! Você acertou em {} tentativas.'.format(tot))
```

---

```
C:\Downloads\pythonexercicios\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Downloads/pythonexercicios/ex058.py
Olá. Sou seu computador...
Acabei de pensar em um número entre 1 e 10.
Será se você consegue advinhar qual foi? 
Qual é seu palpite? 1
6
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
Mais...tente mais uma vez!3
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Downloads\pythonexercicios\ex058.py", line 9, in <module>
    if numero < sorteado:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `print` does not return anything, in fact you can remove that all together, `input` itself will print that string to the terminal

Comment: Oh! Thanks. You fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error happens after the loop starts, when you are not printing the `type()`'s

`print()` returns `None`... I don't think you want `print(int(input())`